# Resque with Redis To Go can't work as expectation

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, redis, resque

I need to use [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) to enqueue my jobs on Heroku.

As it's my first time to use it, I follow the instruction on this site:[Resque with Redis To Go](http://blog.redistogo.com/2010/07/26/resque-with-redis-to-go/).

When I run the command:
$ rake resque:work QUEUE=*

the terminal shows:

```
rake aborted!
Please install the yajl-ruby or json gem

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I had installed both yajl-ruby and json gem after I got the error; however, it didn't work.

If I ignore the problem and enter "rails s" to start the server.
It shows:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque/helpers.rb:6: Please install the yajl-ruby or json gem (RuntimeError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque.rb:10:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque.rb:10
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
from /Users/Brian/Documents/cookie-monster/config/application.rb:7
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6
```

I guess it's a problem of my environment, but I don't know how to solve it.

Please help me, thanks!!

---

mikhailov ask me to paste my Gemfile and Gemfile.lock.
Here it is:
Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'redis'
gem 'SystemTimer'
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    abstract (1.0.0)
    actionmailer (3.0.5)
      actionpack (= 3.0.5)
      mail (~> 2.2.15)
    actionpack (3.0.5)
      activemodel (= 3.0.5)
      activesupport (= 3.0.5)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      erubis (~> 2.6.6)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
      rack (~> 1.2.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.6.13)
      rack-test (~> 0.5.7)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activemodel (3.0.5)
      activesupport (= 3.0.5)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
    activerecord (3.0.5)
      activemodel (= 3.0.5)
      activesupport (= 3.0.5)
      arel (~> 2.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activeresource (3.0.5)
      activemodel (= 3.0.5)
      activesupport (= 3.0.5)
    activesupport (3.0.5)
    arel (2.0.9)
    builder (2.1.2)
    erubis (2.6.6)
      abstract (>= 1.0.0)
    i18n (0.5.0)
    mail (2.2.15)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.6)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.16)
    polyglot (0.3.1)
    rack (1.2.2)
    rack-mount (0.6.14)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-test (0.5.7)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.0.5)
      actionmailer (= 3.0.5)
      actionpack (= 3.0.5)
      activerecord (= 3.0.5)
      activeresource (= 3.0.5)
      activesupport (= 3.0.5)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.0.5)
    railties (3.0.5)
      actionpack (= 3.0.5)
      activesupport (= 3.0.5)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (~> 0.14.4)
    rake (0.9.2)
    redis (2.2.2)
    sqlite3-ruby (1.2.4)
    thor (0.14.6)
    treetop (1.4.9)
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.25)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  rails (= 3.0.5)
  redis
  sqlite3-ruby
```

Comment: copy-paste your **Gemfile** and **Gemfile.lock**

Comment: Gemfile:

source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'redis'
gem 'SystemTimer'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resque has dependence on 'json' gem, so just add it into Gemfile:

```
gem 'json'
```

then Bundler pick the appropriate version to resolve dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You still should use/try:

```
bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=*
```